# My application is not recognizing the database connection

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, connection, sqlconnection

I am building an ASP.NET application. Originally I had it connected to a SQL Server database and everything worked out fine. I then decided to switch the database to another one and reconnect it to the new one however I am running into an error

> The type or namespace name could not be found

I have also provided the code below as well as an image

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private SJAMsSynchTest db = new SJAMsSynchTest();
    //private SJAMsSynchMetroEntities db = new SJAMsSynchMetroEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

[image]

Class:

[image]

Comment: Could you show us your `SJAMsSynchTest` class?

Comment: I pasted an image of the class from the models folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are confusing here, it's not necessary that name of your DBContext class should be same as that of your database object in the server explorer.

From the image that you provided above it's clear that your database object name in the server explorer and your DBContext class' name are not same, that's why,
    "The type or namespace name could not be found"
error is coming.

You need to go into your Context.cs class, in your case,
    "TestDatabase.Context.cs"
and there you can find you DBContext class, like,
[DemoDBEntities image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiUjY.png)

you will find a line in your Context.cs class like,

```
public DemoDBEntities() : base("name=DemoDBEntities")
```

now,
use whatever the name is written after name=, like use - DemoDBEntities
to create your DB object, such as,

```
DemoDBEntities object = new DemoDBEntities();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect your database to your website you need a connection string.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionStringHere"].ConnectionString);
```